# Azure Spot VM with compute gallery Image via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

So, we are using the terraform resource `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` to spin up a Windows VM in Azure. Now when we run the Terraform script for the normal Azure Image, i.e. in attribute `source_image_reference` it works fine, but as soon as we define the Azure compute gallery image using the attribute `source_image_id`, it throws an error.

For FYI, the gallery image resource ID is correct and the image is also working because it works when we manually create it.

Sharing the plan :

```
module.azure-vm-creation.azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.win_vm[0] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "win_vm" {
      + admin_password             = (sensitive value)
      + admin_username             = "adminuser"
      + allow_extension_operations = true
      + computer_name              = "lt-vm"
      + enable_automatic_updates   = true
      + encryption_at_host_enabled = false
      + extensions_time_budget     = "PT1H30M"
      + hotpatching_enabled        = false
      + id                         = (known after apply)
      + license_type               = "Windows_Server"
      + location                   = "eastus"
      + max_bid_price              = -1
      + name                       = "second-vm-test"
      + network_interface_ids      = (known after apply)
      + patch_mode                 = "AutomaticByOS"
      + platform_fault_domain      = -1
      + priority                   = "Regular"
      + private_ip_address         = (known after apply)
      + private_ip_addresses       = (known after apply)
      + provision_vm_agent         = true
      + public_ip_address          = (known after apply)
      + public_ip_addresses        = (known after apply)
      + resource_group_name        = "playground-rg"
      + secure_boot_enabled        = false
      + size                       = "Standard_F2s_v2"
      + source_image_id            = "<Compute Gallary Image Resource ID>"
      + tags                       = {
          + "OS"             = "windows"
          + "Resource group" = "playground-rg"
          + "ResourceName"   = "second-vm-test"
          + "Size"           = "Standard_F2s_v2"
          + "created_by"     = "Soumil"
          + "created_with"   = "terraform"
          + "environment"    = "test"
        }
      + timezone                   = "UTC"
      + virtual_machine_id         = (known after apply)

      + additional_capabilities {
          + ultra_ssd_enabled = false
        }

      + os_disk {
          + caching                   = "ReadWrite"
          + disk_size_gb              = (known after apply)
          + name                      = "second-vm-test-disk"
          + storage_account_type      = "Standard_LRS"
          + write_accelerator_enabled = false
        }

      + termination_notification {
          + enabled = false
          + timeout = "PT5M"
        }
    }
```

Now, the error is :

> Error: creating Windows Virtual Machine: (Name "second-vm-test" / Resource Group "playground-rg"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed." Target="osProfile"

One possible reason which I suspect is that as we are running a prebuilt image, it does not require the username and password but they are mandatory fields in Terraform, so we need to pass them.

Please help me out here !

Answer (score 0):

> `source_image_reference` it works fine, but as soon as we define the Azure compute gallery image using the attribute `source_image_id`, it throws an error.

I created a gallery image and created another `VM` by using same gallery image using Terraform.

> The 'osProfile' is not allowed cause of Admin username, password, or SSH keys were provided for a VM that was created from a specialized image version. Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting-shared-images#creating-or-updating-a-vm-or-scale-sets-from-an-image-version)  for your reference.

To check the `Azure gallery image resource ID` follow the below steps.

1. Go to **Azure compute galleries > Select your gallery image > definition > select your image > Select Json View**

> Note:  If you try to create an image from a gallery image that has the security type: Trusted Launch, you will get the following error.
> Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type."

[image]

**Terraform Code:**

```
    provider "azurerm"  {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name = "vmresourcegroup"
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
      name                = "vmgallery-network"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
      name                 = "galleryinternal"
      resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
    }
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
      name                = "vmgallery-nic"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      ip_configuration {
        name                          = "testconfiguration1"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "testingvm" {
      name                        = "galleryimage"
      resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      vm_size                     = "Standard_DS1_v2"
      network_interface_ids       = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
    
      storage_image_reference {
        id = "/subscriptions/ahdjd d f hff-bd66-bfhffhf/resourceGroups/vmresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/galleryimage/images/galleryimage"  
        }
      storage_os_disk {
        name                      = "galleryimage-os"
        caching                   = "ReadWrite"
        create_option             = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type         = "Standard_LRS"
      }
      os_profile {
        computer_name  = "venkatgalleryimage"
        admin_username = "Venkat"
        admin_password = "Password1234!"
      }
     os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
      }
    }
```

**Terraform Plan:**

[image]

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code, `Azure VM` is created successfully in portal.

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkat, you are right, and we can create the VM using the terraform resource `azurerm_virtual_machine`, but the BIGGEST blocker is that the `azurerm_virtual_machine` has no support for the SPOT VMs. My Use case is, 
Create an Azure Windows SPOT Virtual Machine with compute gallery Image via terraform. The use case is extremely straight forward but somehow I am unable to get to right !! I appreciate your help, please have a look at this use case.

Comment: You Can use Azure CLI commands within Terraform to create the SPOT VM.
Here is the script 
resource "null_resource" "create_spot_vm" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
  [Az Vm Create Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create)
EOT
  }
}